# What is a $U(1)-$bundle over a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth curve over $\mathbb C$. An $U(1)-$principal bundle over $X$ is a  **flat unitary line bundle**. What is the exact definition of the latter? Is it a line bundle over $X$ with a hermitian form?

Thanks